# What size flexible toilet supply line will fit my shut-off valve?

Tags: toilet

I have a rigid toilet supply line that needs to be changed to a flexible one for a bidet seat. It seems there are 2 sizes (3/8” or 1/2”) at the compression end, however the current rigid compression end is between those measurements - 3/8” is too small and 1/2” is too big.

Do I have to completely replace the valve so I’m able to get a supply line that fits or is there an adapter?

[image]

Comment: You use the inside diameter measurement of the pipe, usually the exact measurement might not match, but quite close to the nominal size of the pipe.  The valve if I guess, is 1/2x3/8(just a guess), so a 3/8 flex should fit on

Answer (score 5):

I would buy one of each (3/8" and 1/2"), take them both home, and see which one screws on.

Once you know what size you need, return the other one.

If, by some rare chance *neither* fit, return them both then look for the Goldilocks Adapter™ - the one that's not too big, not too small, but just right... You might have to buy several that *could* fit, take them home to find out which one *does* fit, then return the rest.

You won't be the first one to do so, and you'll be far from the last to do this. There's a reason all the big-box stores have a return desk right inside the main entry doors...

To avoid the extra trip to the store, just stop by on your way home from work, your next shopping trip out to that part of town, make the return and bring your significant other to make a date of it, whatever...

Comment: You could also minimize return trips by purchasing a new angle stop... the brasscraft 29 is 1/2 copper (sweat or compression) to 3/8 fitting.

Comment: Then, however, @AloysiusDefenestrate, it's a matter of picking the right valve to fit the in-wall plumbing and _that_ could require buying a couple of options... :D _good point_

Comment: Agree, @freeman, but that *looks* like 1/2" copper coming out of the wall...

Comment: *I would buy one of each (3/8" and 1/2"), take them both home, and see which one screws on.* **Exactly**. I was in Home Depot one time in a very similar situation. The employee actually told me to do exactly that and return whichever one I didn't use. It isn't trying to sneak something past them - it is normal and expected for these types of items.

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. Just be sure to not remove tags, labels, etc. If you return it in saleable condition, they won't even bat an eye. If it's slightly damaged, they may look at you funny, but odds are good they'll accept it anyway.

Comment: Alternately, take the old rigid line and see what size valve it fits in the store.  Then buy a flexible supply line that fits that valve.  Fewer trips to the store needed.  (Might as well buy a repair kit for the valve while you're there.)